# RabbitMQ and RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE

Tags: rabbitmq

I have updated to the latest version of RabbitMQ (from a 3.6) and I can not use the file defined in the environment variable: RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE. I have the variable as: C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq, and there is a file rabbitmq.config in the path "C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server", but RabbitMQ does not use it, neither as a windows service nor starting with rabbitmq -server.bat.
In the log:

- Server:

  config file(s) : (none)
- Service:

  config file(s) : d:/Users/jandres/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/advanced.config
              : c:/Program.conf

Comment: How did you perform the upgrade? Did you install `3.7.3` using the `jandres` account, and if so, is that user an administrator or did you use an administrative prompt to run the `.exe` installer? You should be able to *remove* the `RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable and put your configuration file ending in `*.config` or `*.conf` in the `%AppData%\RabbitMQ` directory for the `jandres` user, which should be `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ`

Comment: I did the update as always, with my user and with administrator permissions. The solution I have found is to use the path you mention: "d: /Users/jandres/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/advanced.config", but I would like to continue using the "RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE" variable  because it helps me to have the same configuration on different computers .
Thank you very much for the reply.